# xamarin forms - two way binding with a picker - why cant I update a picker from code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

My products page only shows 'Product Name' and 'Quantity', quantity isdisplayed/ binded to the picker.

For test purposes to get this working there is only 2 products loading from the VM. Wine 1 and wine 2.

**When the application loads, why is the picker empty with no value selected. When quantity for each item is set to 1, when loading from the VM**

Quantity is set to 1, the picker is just not updating when it initially loads, I know this because if I click on the empty picker and select 1. nothing happens because the code hits

```
if (quantity != value)
```

// where quantity 1 being selected is already 1 in code behind, so wont call propertyChanged from setter in quantity,

also...
if I select the picker and choose another number, say 4 for example. the setter in quantity is hit and OnPropertyChanged is hit, and 4 is displayed on the picker.
(I even tested changing the productName if 3 was picked)
and this worked.

I know this all works as I have stepped through the code. **However another issue that is now happening is that for some reason the code is hitting the quantity get/set AGAIN and setting the value to 0, after everytime it is clicked.**

So for example if 4 is clicked, the picker will be updated to 4 on screen, then if I follow it through stepping in the code, the setter in quantity is called again, setting the value to 0, and thus selecting nothing in the picker. Leaving it blank, as it is when it initially loads.

any help to help resolve this would be appreciated thank Y

thank Y for any help received

```
public class ProductModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private int quantity;
        private string productName;

        public ProductModel()
        { }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string ProductName
        {
            get
            {
                return productName;
            }
            set
            {
                productName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get
            {
                return quantity;
            }
            set
            {
                if (quantity != value)
                {
                    quantity = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();

                    //test to check if binding works, successfully changed ProductName to "test" if 3 is picked from picker
                    if (quantity == 3)
                        ProductName = "test;";
                }

            }
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }
    public class ProductPageViewModel : BindableObject
        {
           public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> WineList { get; set; }
            public ProductPageViewModel ()
            {
                WineList = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
                WineList.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Wine 1", Quantity = 1});
                WineList.Add(new ProductModel { ProductId = 2, ProductName = "Wine 2", Quantity = 1});
            }
   
        
    
    
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScrollApp2.Views.ProductPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
         
            <ListView  x:Name="producttablelist" IsVisible="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding WineList}" HeightRequest="1500">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="120" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>

                                    <Picker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Quantity,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <Picker.Items>
                                            <x:String>0</x:String>
                                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                                            <x:String>3</x:String>
                                            <x:String>4</x:String>
                                            <x:String>5</x:String>
                                            <x:String>6</x:String>
                                        </Picker.Items>
                                    </Picker>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            
        </StackLayout>
       
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

    
   namespace ScrollApp2.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProductPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ProductPageViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not need to use "SelectedIndexChanged="QuantityChanged" " on your Quantity picker, since you are bound to property, you can simply handle that code when the property changes. You will need to add the following code to your blank 'ProductModel' constructor. "this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged", and override the method to capture the event. Then process the required code when the property that is changing == nameof(Quantity)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have tried my best with what you suggested and ran into difficulty if you could please take a look at the updated Q any help would be grateful thank Y

Comment: Yes, you are close now. I am going to move to an actual post for easier code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your `ProductModel` class does not inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you’ll need to add the interface to your class and implement it, also making sure to raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event in `Quantity` setter.</strike>

You might want to create a `ProductViewModel` at this point, as I’m not sure you want to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to a POCO class like `ProductModel`.

---

Please don't edit your question with a different one, open a new question. Your previous question might have helped someone else facing the same problem of UI not being updated when changing a property of a class that does not inherit from `IPropertyChanged`. My previous answer is now irrelevant to the new question, and will never benefit anyone else.

For your new question, your `Quantity` is of type `int` and your picker items are of type `string`, changing `Quantity` type to `string` should help solving your issue, you can also use `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem` if the index of the items are matching.

```xml
<Picker SelectedIndex="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>0</x:String>
        <x:String>1</x:String>
        <x:String>2</x:String>
        <x:String>3</x:String>
        <x:String>4</x:String>
        <x:String>5</x:String>
        <x:String>6</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have tried my best with what you suggested and ran into difficulty if you could please take a look at the updated Q any help would be grateful thank Y

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help with that, It resolved the issue of 'When the application loads, why is the picker empty with no value selected. When quantity for each item is set to 1, when loading from the VM'. Im marking this as the correct answer but I needed both answers to resolve my issue so have wrote another Q and commented that the second part of the Q was also answered by ReRoute, again Roger, thanks for helping me with this. Much appreciated. For future ref will know to keep 1 question to 1 post and apologises for any confusion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64437205/xamarin-forms-two-way-binding-with-a-picker-why-cant-i-update-a-picker-from

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have properly implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `ProductModel`, but now you need to subscribe to it in the constructor of the `ProductModel` class.

I have stubbed up a simple implementation of what it is that you are looking for (I excluded the rest of your code so that it would be easier to digest)

```
public class ProductModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        
        //Event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        //Fields
        private string _ProductName;
        private int _Quantity;

        //Properties
        public int Quantity {
            get { return _Quantity; }
            set {
                _Quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string ProductName {
            get { return _ProductName; }
            set {
                _ProductName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        //Constructor
        public ProductModel() {
            //Subscription
            this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }

        //OnPropertyChanged
        private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Quantity)) {
                //Do anything that needs doing when the Quantity changes here...
            }
        }

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this gets you going

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with that. I made the mistake of needing two questions to resolve my issue. I have marked the other answer as it helped resolve the first part of the issue, but I needed your answer to help with the correct post back and updating. please accept my apologises or the confusion. I wanted to acknowledge your help so I wrote another Q, if you post your answer there I will mark it as correct. Thanks again for taking the time to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64437205/xamarin-forms-two-way-binding-with-a-picker-why-cant-i-update-a-picker-from

Comment: That's ok. Im just glad you got it working. No worries about credit due, I help people on here for fun because I like to code.